# IBM MFP 8.0 ios crashes when request data from secured adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've implemented the following:

1. Create adapter with custom security check
2. Creat scope "main" and assign it to my security check
3. Create adapter for accessing data with 
   @OAuthSecurity(scope = "main")
4. IOS class inherited from SecurityCheckChallengeHandler
5. IOS app crashes on requesting data from adapter. 
   If I disable security check all works fine. App crashes before calling "handleChallenge"

Log from XCode console:

```
objc[2527]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11a098998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119e26d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-11-28 16:25:04.800 fiorimfp[2527:119968] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/aleks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B5A1053-1175-4E95-8045-21CB084E7ECA/data/Containers/Data/Application/00A7BCA1-6996-4A93-9738-0EF0BFC07D7C/Library/Cookies/ru.sberbank.fiorimfp.binarycookies
2016-11-28 16:25:05.052 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.0 is starting.
2016-11-28 16:25:05.053 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-11-28 16:25:05.089 fiorimfp[2527:119968] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file

2016-11-28 16:25:06.120 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Using UIWebView
2016-11-28 16:25:06.122 fiorimfp[2527:119968] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.141978ms
2016-11-28 16:25:06.136 fiorimfp[2527:119968] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 14.124990ms
2016-11-28 16:25:06.137 fiorimfp[2527:119968] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.104964ms
2016-11-28 16:25:06.137 fiorimfp[2527:119968] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 15.310049ms
2016-11-28 16:25:17.007 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Testing Server Connection
2016-11-28 16:25:17.259 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Received the following access token value: (null)
2016-11-28 16:25:17.288 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Could not add the Keychain Item.
2016-11-28 16:25:17.328608 fiorimfp[2527:120679] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2016-11-28 16:25:17.329498 fiorimfp[2527:120679] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2016-11-28 16:25:17.336809 fiorimfp[2527:120679] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000110b25682 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a9c932 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3100
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a7a4f4 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a79511 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a78270 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a9344d nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000111a92e7c nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108a2980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108cc0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108a9e6b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108aab9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108ad3b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001108ad08b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110d584de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110d56341 start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: Please provide actual reproducible sample application and security check so this could be debugged.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a requirement in Xcode 8 to add the "Keychain sharing" capability (from the Capabilities tab in Xcode). I've seen apps crash in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 due to this.

```
2016-11-28 16:25:17.259 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Received the following access token value: (null)
2016-11-28 16:25:17.288 fiorimfp[2527:119968] Could not add the Keychain Item.
```

Try adding the missing(?) capability and see if this resolves the crashing.

For reference, see here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

> Note: The Keychain Sharing capability is mandatory while running iOS apps in the iOS Simulator when using Xcode 8. You need to enable this capability manually before building the Xcode project.